# Build several CDT C++ projects from commandline

Tags: eclipse, command-line, eclipse-cdt

What is the best solution to build several CDT C++ projects from the command line? The projects have references and so it is not possible to just build single projects.

Comment: Have you considered using [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake)?

Comment: Make uses the .mk files generated by CDT on build. So it isn't possible to build the project from scratch.

Comment: This is one of the big weaknesses of Eclipse in general, I think. Headless builds are not a first class citizen in the Eclipse world.

Answer (score 65):

This feature has been added in CDT 6 (Final build due June 15th 2009). You can download the final release candidate from builds page: download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/6.0.0/.

Using a release of Eclipse 3.5 + CDT 6, you can import, build and clean-build projects and the workspace using the following options sent to Eclipse at the command line:

```
eclipse -nosplash 
        -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild 
        -import {[uri:/]/path/to/project} 
        -build {project_name | all} 
        -cleanBuild {projec_name | all}
```

On Windows, use [`eclipsec.exe`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F) instead of `eclipse.exe` to have build output written to stdout/stderr and so that the call blocks until completion.

The '*-application*' switch instructs Eclipse to run the CDT headless builder rather than starting the workbench.  The other switches can be used individually or together. This means you can checkout a project using a shell script of your own, '*-import*' it into a workspace, and '*-build*' it using the Managedbuilder's headless builder.

Use the '*-data*' switch to specify the workspace to use, which can be an empty temporary directory, see the runtime documentation for other switches supported by the platform runtime: 
[help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)

See [bug 186847 comment 24](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=186847#c24) and onwards for more detail on the committed functionality.

Comment: In addition, you can specify a single configuration with: `-build {project_name[/config_name] | all}` Example: `-build project_name/Release`

Answer (score 1):

Pre CDT 6 you could use the JDT's [AptBuilder](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/apt/org/eclipse/jdt/apt/core/build/package-summary.html) (included with classic Eclipse, for example).

This lets you build an already configured workspace.  So you: checkout your source, configure a workspace which points to the checked-out projects.  Your automated build scripts can then  update the checkouts and run the AptBuilder without needing to start the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a Make project under CDT you can just use your favorite shell and execute make in all the projects dirs.

Comment: This is the answer to your question.  You need to "mess around with Makefiles".  Eclipse is not a build system.

Comment: @Jesse: This is only a half answer. And it wouldn't be an answer if I had written that our projects are not Make projects. Because changing the pre-conditions of a question is not the answer to it.

Comment: New URL for @JesseWeigert comment is: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-f5-key-is-not-a-build-process/

Answer (score 0):

Headless build with the manage builder is currently not supported, see [bug 186847 - CDT internal builder does not support automated command line builds](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=186847).

If you use the unmanaged (make) builder, then you already have Makefiles that you can use from the command line.

Comment: This is no longer true. That bug has been fixed.

Answer (score -1):

We do this in our existing build.

Put a makefile in all your external references and your toplevel project.
In your "all" rule, have it run:
make -C ./externalref1
make -C ./externalref2
etc

we actually define the external dependencies in a variable:
EXT_DEP = externalref1 externalref2
then use the subst (substitute) command to kick off all the sub-makes using the correct call.