# Is there a headless way to import projects and refresh the workspace?

Tags: eclipse, build, headless, pde

Still trying to set up an headless build for a big university project (RCP product).

Every Eclipse user knows the following manual functionality:
"File --> Import --> Existing projects into workspace"
as well as "Build Workspace" and "Clean Workspace"

Is there a way to invoke this actions headlessly?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I answered a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087573/open-a-specific-eclipse-project-from-command-line) with a hacky little plugin to import projects. This may help, or at least show you how to implement a similar plugin yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet but you can expect it soon. Work is in progress on [Bug 320552](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=320552) .

Answer (score 0):

Ant4Eclipse has a task that can do this: [workspaceDefinition](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/node/127). It takes the directory in which to create the workspace and a list of directories to search for projects, and adds any projects it discovers to the new workspace.

I don't think it can add a project to an existing workspace. I'm also not clear on whether it can register a project that is within the workspace directory (and keeps its relative path if the workspace is moved); it seems the project must have an external, absolute pathname.