# eclipse command line switch to start with project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

What is the command line option to start eclipse with a specific project?

I can get the correct workspace using -data.

Within that workspace, I want to have a specific project loaded, similar to the "Go Into" command.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087573/open-a-specific-eclipse-project-from-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such an option right now.

Oening a file from the command line has only taken 9 years: [bug 4922](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4922):
If your Eclipse Helios 3.6 `eclipse.ini` file contains "`--launcher.defaultAction`", you can open any file with:

```
eclipse.exe myFile
```

But open directly a project is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087573/open-a-specific-eclipse-project-from-command-line) SO question which contains an Eclipse plugin that only loads specific projects (which are defined in a config file) into the workspace.