# Spawning new project via batch including eclipse

Tags: eclipse, command-line-interface, eclipse-wtp

I'm in the process of making several decisions about the "build new" step of my current base project.  This is a project that I'm using to automate the build for web projects to suit my personal needs.

I have a lot of flexibility here in terms of implementation but I have very specific targets in mind.

One of these targets is

```
Once the build of new folders is complete, create a new project in Eclipse.
```

I am currently doing a copy and paste in Eclipse to launch the entire project, but I'm certain there must be a better way.

For this question specifically, what CLI call would  allow me to create a *new* project inside an existing workspace?

I am aware of questions [Create an Eclipse project on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718456/create-an-eclipse-project-on-the-command-line), [open a specific eclipse project from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087573/open-a-specific-eclipse-project-from-command-line) and this page: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F   however none seem to specifically resolve my need.