# How to open a file in eclipse (current project) from command line?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have recently switched to eclipse as IDT for my c++ code earlier i was using vim for editing my code.

Most of the time I have full path for the file I need to edit and it is quite a pain to reach the file in eclipse using navigator or search.

Is there a way to communicate with currently running instance of eclipse to notify it to open a file in current project from command line?

Comment: Not the command line, but you can enter the path (relative to the workspace root) in the `Navigate / Open Resources` dialog.

Answer (score 0):

See [open a specific eclipse project from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087573/open-a-specific-eclipse-project-from-command-line)

e.g. for CDT (C projects)

> eclipse -nosplash -data /home/$USER/dev -application
> org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import
> /home/$USER/dev/src_dir