# Can one build Eclipse projects from the command line?

Tags: command-line, eclipse-cdt

I would like to know if the issue of building Eclipse CDT projects from the command line has been resolved. I am unable to get this feature to work.

I am using Eclipse Indigo CDT.

I have three separate command line invocations of Eclipse.
Two commands import two projects into a workspace. There are no errors with the import commands.

The third command performs the build. The first project builds. The second project fails during build. The first project is essentially a makefile build, build instructions are not generated by Eclipse. The second project's build instructions are generated by Eclipse.

I am executing the commands in a empty directory. The .metadata directory is created.

I have eliminated the build step and opened the workspace manually. The projects build in the IDE.

I am using the command line format described in this link from 2009.
[Build several CDT C++ projects from commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344797/build-several-cdt-c-projects-from-commandline)

This Eclipse bug is described here. But reading of the conversation seems to indicate the issue was not resolved. Last entry is May 2010.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=186847

Below are the error messages from Eclipse .metadata/.log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2012-07-18 11:28:05.705
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-18 11:28:09.626
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui (98).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui.
....

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.core 4 0 2012-07-18 11:28:09.641
!MESSAGE Error: org/eclipse/cdt/debug/ui/ICDebuggerPage
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/cdt/debug/ui/ICDebuggerPage
....

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2012-07-18 11:28:09.641
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "C/C++ Indexer".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/cdt/debug/ui/ICDebuggerPage
....

!SESSION 2012-07-18 11:28:10.688 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.6.0_31
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -build all
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data . -build all

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2012-07-18 11:28:11.594
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-18 11:28:21.778
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui (98).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui.
....

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2012-07-18 11:28:21.778
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/cdt/debug/ui/ICDebuggerPage
....

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-18 11:28:22.231
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui (48).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.CDebugUIPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.
....

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2012-07-18 11:28:22.231
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/cdt/debug/ui/ICDebuggerPage
....
```

Here is the last error in detail. Some detail has been eliminated to fit into stackoverflow character limit.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-18 11:28:24.137
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Errors occurred during the build.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.HeadlessBuilder.start(HeadlessBuilder.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Contains: Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'src'.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/cdt/debug/ui/ICDebuggerPage
    at com.ecoscentric.cdt.builder.MacroSupplier$ecComputedMacro.getEcosInstallDir(MacroSupplier.java:95)
    at com.ecoscentric.cdt.builder.MacroSupplier$ecosInstallDirMacro.getStringValue(MacroSupplier.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.getResolvedMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.PathInfo.isAbsolute(PathInfo.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.PathInfo.checkIsAbsolute(PathInfo.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.PathInfo.isAbsolute(PathInfo.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.fromBuildToProj(BuildEntryStorage.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.createUserEntry(BuildEntryStorage.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.getUserEntries(BuildEntryStorage.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.putEntriesToLevel(BuildEntryStorage.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.util.AbstractEntryStorage.initCache(AbstractEntryStorage.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.util.AbstractEntryStorage.getEntries(AbstractEntryStorage.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildLanguageData.getEntries(BuildLanguageData.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultLanguageData.getEntriesToCopy(CDefaultLanguageData.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultLanguageData.createStore(CDefaultLanguageData.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultLanguageData.copySettingsFrom(CDefaultLanguageData.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CLanguageSettingCache.copySettingsFrom(CLanguageSettingCache.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CLanguageSettingCache.<init>(CLanguageSettingCache.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CFolderDescriptionCache.copyLanguageData(CFolderDescriptionCache.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultFolderData.copyDataFrom(CDefaultFolderData.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CFolderDescriptionCache.<init>(CFolderDescriptionCache.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.copyFolderData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultConfigurationData.copySettingsFrom(CDefaultConfigurationData.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.CoreModel.getProjectDescription(CoreModel.java:1423)
    .....
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui (98).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.startup(LaunchingResourceManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.getLaunchingResourceManager(DebugUIPlugin.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start(DebugUIPlugin.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 78 more
Contains: Errors running builder 'Scanner Configuration Builder' on project 'src'.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/cdt/debug/ui/ICDebuggerPage
    at com.ecoscentric.cdt.builder.MacroSupplier$ecComputedMacro.getEcosInstallDir(MacroSupplier.java:95)
    at com.ecoscentric.cdt.builder.MacroSupplier$ecosInstallDirMacro.getStringValue(MacroSupplier.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.getResolvedMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.PathInfo.isAbsolute(PathInfo.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.PathInfo.checkIsAbsolute(PathInfo.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.PathInfo.isAbsolute(PathInfo.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.fromBuildToProj(BuildEntryStorage.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.createUserEntry(BuildEntryStorage.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.getUserEntries(BuildEntryStorage.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.putEntriesToLevel(BuildEntryStorage.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.util.AbstractEntryStorage.initCache(AbstractEntryStorage.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.util.AbstractEntryStorage.getEntries(AbstractEntryStorage.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildLanguageData.getEntries(BuildLanguageData.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultLanguageData.getEntriesToCopy(CDefaultLanguageData.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultLanguageData.createStore(CDefaultLanguageData.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultLanguageData.copySettingsFrom(CDefaultLanguageData.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CLanguageSettingCache.copySettingsFrom(CLanguageSettingCache.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CLanguageSettingCache.<init>(CLanguageSettingCache.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CFolderDescriptionCache.copyLanguageData(CFolderDescriptionCache.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultFolderData.copyDataFrom(CDefaultFolderData.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CFolderDescriptionCache.<init>(CFolderDescriptionCache.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.copyFolderData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultConfigurationData.copySettingsFrom(CDefaultConfigurationData.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.CConfigBasedDescriptorManager.findDescriptor(CConfigBasedDescriptorManager.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.CConfigBasedDescriptorManager.getDescriptor(CConfigBasedDescriptorManager.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.CCorePlugin.getCProjectDescription(CCorePlugin.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.make.internal.core.scannerconfig2.ScannerConfigInfoFactory2$ScannerConfigInfoSet.load(ScannerConfigInfoFactory2.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.make.internal.core.scannerconfig2.ScannerConfigInfoFactory2$ScannerConfigInfoSet.<init>(ScannerConfigInfoFactory2.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.make.internal.core.scannerconfig2.ScannerConfigInfoFactory2.createInfoSet(ScannerConfigInfoFactory2.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.make.internal.core.scannerconfig2.ScannerConfigProfileManager.createScannerConfigBuildInfo2Set(ScannerConfigProfileManager.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.build.internal.core.scannerconfig2.CfgScannerConfigInfoFactory2$CfgInfo.getContainer(CfgScannerConfigInfoFactory2.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.build.internal.core.scannerconfig2.CfgScannerConfigInfoFactory2$CfgInfo.createMap(CfgScannerConfigInfoFactory2.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.build.internal.core.scannerconfig2.CfgScannerConfigInfoFactory2$CfgInfo.getInfoMap(CfgScannerConfigInfoFactory2.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.scannerconfig.ScannerConfigBuilder.build(ScannerConfigBuilder.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.scannerconfig.ScannerConfigBuilder.build(ScannerConfigBuilder.java:119)
    .....
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui (48).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.CDebugUIPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/debug/ui/ISourcePresentation
    at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.CDebugUIPlugin.start(CDebugUIPlugin.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui (98).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ecoscentric.cdt.builder.MacroSupplier$ecComputedMacro.getEcosInstallDir(MacroSupplier.java:95)
    at com.ecoscentric.cdt.builder.MacroSupplier$ecosInstallDirMacro.getStringValue(MacroSupplier.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.getResolvedMacro(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.cdtvariables.SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.resolveToString(SupplierBasedCdtVariableSubstitutor.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.PathInfo.isAbsolute(PathInfo.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.PathInfo.checkIsAbsolute(PathInfo.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.PathInfo.isAbsolute(PathInfo.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.fromBuildToProj(BuildEntryStorage.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.createUserEntry(BuildEntryStorage.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.getUserEntries(BuildEntryStorage.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildEntryStorage.putEntriesToLevel(BuildEntryStorage.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.util.AbstractEntryStorage.initCache(AbstractEntryStorage.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.util.AbstractEntryStorage.getEntries(AbstractEntryStorage.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.dataprovider.BuildLanguageData.getEntries(BuildLanguageData.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultLanguageData.getEntriesToCopy(CDefaultLanguageData.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultLanguageData.createStore(CDefaultLanguageData.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultLanguageData.copySettingsFrom(CDefaultLanguageData.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CLanguageSettingCache.copySettingsFrom(CLanguageSettingCache.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CLanguageSettingCache.<init>(CLanguageSettingCache.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CFolderDescriptionCache.copyLanguageData(CFolderDescriptionCache.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultFolderData.copyDataFrom(CDefaultFolderData.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CFolderDescriptionCache.<init>(CFolderDescriptionCache.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.copyFolderData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings.model.extension.impl.CDefaultConfigurationData.copySettingsFrom(CDefaultConfigurationData.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.CoreModel.getProjectDescription(CoreModel.java:1423)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.isCdtProjectCreated(CommonBuilder.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:431)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.startup(LaunchingResourceManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.getLaunchingResourceManager(DebugUIPlugin.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start(DebugUIPlugin.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 78 more
```

Comment: Here 2 links (I know links are bad here) to a How To. http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/advanced/headless-builds/  https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/09/12/building-projects-with-eclipse-from-the-command-line/  It is possible to build from the command line with Indigo CDT.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing exactly same problem with ecos configured projects i.e. projects using ecos toolchain for cross compilation. For an experiment, I selected Cross GCC toolchain and applied all the project setting manually on a hello world project, and it builds well from command line. It seems that something is wrong when the projects are automatically configurd by ecos toolchain.

Thanks,
Sushil