# Eclipse CDT C project continuous integration with Jenkins

Tags: c, macos, jenkins, eclipse-cdt

I have been developing c project using Eclipse CDT on MAC OSX.
Now I want to setup continuous integration with jenkins. I have look through the plugins in jenkins but there is no plugin for Eclipse builds.
I believe I have two options to deal with this situation.

1. I look for plugin for Eclipse
2. I develop a shell script which will load the project in Eclipse and build it for me every time.

For the second option I am looking for command or script that can do eclipse build for me.
I am asking here two questions at the same time but I would really appreciate answer in any direction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344797/build-several-cdt-c-projects-from-commandline/962610#962610

Comment: You want a `headless build`; see http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/advanced/headless-builds/