# How can I mimic Eclipse build in bash

Tags: eclipse

The build button of Eclipse compiles the project (in my case, the project is very huge and complex). Is there a way to clone the build scripts of Eclipse and run these cloned scripts in my own bash shell? I do not want to run Eclipse (neither in window nor in `nosplash` mode), I want to compile the project in bash using only `make`.

Comment: You can export eclipse build script as `ant` build.xml, or try `maven` or `gradle`

Comment: Which language? Java, C/C++, ...? In case of C/C++, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/344797/6505250

Comment: @howlger, I need C++. Your solution runs Eclipse in `nosplash` mode. I need to run the build scripts using `make` etc.

Comment: @Kadir The solution does not run the Eclipse IDE application, it runs only the Java code that reads your project configuration and based on this, it builds your project, e. g. executes `make` (`-application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild`). Instead of `eclipse ...` you should use `eclipsec ...` (the suffix `c` means command line mode).